# console.log logs are not showing in Xcode debug logger and either not on the Safari debug logger

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, debugging, ios-simulator

I created index.html file under cordova/www. Run it through iOS simulator and just doing this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>   <title>Title</title> </head> <body>

    <h1>Hello World1</h1>
    <h2>Test this out</h2>
    <h2 id="test"></h2>

    <script>
      console.log("Test")
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "text string"
    </script>

</html>
```

The HTML output is presented in the simulator, and the `<h2 id="test"></h2>` is also filled with the "text string" string - means JS is enabled.

But, the `console.log("Test")` doesn't appear anywhere - not on the Xcode debug and neither in the Debug I ran from the Safari.

Howcome and how to fix this